# How to find out how many and what are the tables in my database?

Tags: mysql

I want to know how many tables are there in my database server and what are they.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can request the tables from a certain database by executing the following SQL commands:

```
USE <database-name>;
SHOW TABLES;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can fire query as below

```
SELECT * from information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: if you are going to blatantly copy and paste tag wikis, please attribute the source at the end of the tag wiki.  This should not have been approved, as it was plagiarized text:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1171792

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Hey I am editing wiki tags so that SO users can understand the tags requirements, though instead appriciating my work you are accusing me.

Comment: I'm not accusing, I'm stating a fact: you copied another's text without citing it; that is not improving this site.  I and others don't appreciate people copying other people's work without credit.  It takes only a few seconds to properly attribute where you are getting your information from.  See this meta link:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148420/tag-wiki-edits-rejected.

Answer (score -1):

**-- In MS-SQL Server, Retrieve all TableName from Database.**

SELECT * FROM sys.tables;